# Property similar to Label.Target for a custom templated control

Tags: wpf, keyboard-shortcuts, datatemplate, controltemplate

I have a control which template contains a generic `ContentPresenter`. This ContentPresenter will normally contain an `AccessText` (possibly amongst other things), whose AccessKey should focus the whole control. How do I do that?

Here is a specific but much simplified example to my case. (I know it could be implemented in several other ways (e.g. `UserControl`), but I need it this way for various reasons). I just made it up, there are minor omissions; the point is only to show the idea.

Imagine I want to add a header to the `TextBox`. I subclass it into a `TextBoxEx` and add two dependency properties `Header` and `HeaderTemplate`, similarly to `HeaderedContentControl`. (Code is trivial and omitted).

Then I assign a template to my `TextBoxEx` along these lines:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBoxEx">
  <StackPanel>
    <ContentPresenter Name="PART_Header"
      Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
      RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
    <TextBox ... /> <!--or some other components with similar functionality-->
  </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

When using this control, I might do something like this:

```
<TextBoxEx Template="{StaticResource TemplateAbove}" Header="_Test">
  <TextBoxEx.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <AccessText Text="{Binding}" FontSize="14" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </TextBoxEx.HeaderTemplate>
</TextBoxEx>
```

(Of course, in reality it is done via styles and is more elaborate, but I tried to conflate it to a minimal code).

Now, this all renders fine. The only problem is that when I press Alt+T, nothing happens. (Except for underlining the T). What I want is for the control to get focus - which is the usual action OnAccessKey.

Typicaly, such things are done using a `Label`, which has the `Target` property, which can point to the control to be focused. But here at the `ControlTemplate` level, I don't know what header template the user will use; it may not have anything `AccessText`-related at all, and I don't want to restrict it in any way. Yet if such control is used, I want the access key to work. Supposedly, `ContentPresenter.RecognizesAccessKey` should help, but how do I tell it what exactly to do, i.e. what (sub-)control to focus?

Or is there another easier approach (but still, on a template level)?

P.S. The problem can be solved by replacing the `ContentPresenter` with `Label` as follows:

```
<Label Name="PART_Header"
  Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
  Target="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}} />
```

But I feel this is not the 'right' way to do it and I'm still missing something fundamental, so I'll happily listen to any suggestions.

Comment: `<AccessText Text="{Binding}"` - what's that? What's the DataContext here?

Comment: @mechanic, `Header`; that `_Text` ends up there. This part works, and the `AccessText` clearly sees the access key T. I just don't see any meaningful action; `OnAccessKey` is not called for the control (`TextBoxEx`).